# Chain index stop syncing after slot 62510369, maybe related with new Babbage era

Tags: error, syncing, chain-index

Chain index is not syncing in tesnet after Slot: 62510369,
BlockId: d931221f9bc4cae34de422d9f4281a2b0344e86aac6b31eb54e2ee90f44a09b9

I converted to POSIX TIME and is: Friday, 22 July 2022 8:19:45.999 AM, related with the time frame of the new babbage era.

I download and built the latest plutus apps (commit 139c0429f2c7a656ff6114e6373f895d29132860) and syncing from zero again with no success.
Im using with cardano-node-1.35.0-linux which is syncing 100%.

There was similar issues with cardano-db-sync and they said they fix the issue there.
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/issues/1181
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/issues/1182

Here also, some report about the chain index rolling back slots after this slot:
https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/pull/557

Any idea?

Im Running in WSL2 with Ubuntu.

The message from chain index is:

[chain-index:Info:33] [2022-07-17 01:06:05.64 UTC] Syncing (98.21%). Processed 0 blocks, 1 rollbacks in the last 12s. Current tip is Point(Slot 62510369, BlockId d931221f9bc4cae34de422d9f4281a2b0344e86aac6b31eb54e2ee90f44a09b9)

Here is full detaiuled run of chain index with verbose:

```
Command line config:
AppConfig {acLogConfigPath = Nothing, acMinLogLevel = Just Debug, acConfigPath = Just "/home/manuelpadilla/source/cardano-falcon-stakepool-devs/cardano-falcon-stakepol-devs-haskell/files/config/cardano-chain-index/chain-index-config.json", acCLIConfigOverrides = CLIConfigOverrides {ccSocketPath = Nothing, ccDbPath = Nothing, ccPort = Nothing, ccNetworkId = Nothing, ccAppendTransactionQueueSize = Nothing}, acCommand = StartChainIndex}

Logging config:
Representation {minSeverity = Debug, rotation = Nothing, setupScribes = [ScribeDefinition {scKind = StdoutSK, scFormat = ScText, scName = "stdout", scPrivacy = ScPublic, scRotation = Nothing, scMinSev = Debug, scMaxSev = Emergency}], defaultScribes = [(StdoutSK,"stdout")], setupBackends = [KatipBK,AggregationBK,MonitoringBK,EKGViewBK], defaultBackends = [KatipBK,AggregationBK,EKGViewBK], hasEKG = Just (Endpoint ("localhost",12790)), hasGraylog = Nothing, hasPrometheus = Nothing, hasGUI = Nothing, traceForwardTo = Nothing, forwardDelay = Nothing, traceAcceptAt = Nothing, options = fromList []}

Chain Index config:
Socket: /home/manuelpadilla/source/tools/cardano-node-1.35.0-linux2/db/node.socket
Db: /home/manuelpadilla/source/tools/cardano-chain-index/chain-index.db
Port: 9083
Network Id: Testnet (NetworkMagic {unNetworkMagic = 1097911063})
Security Param: 2160
Store from: BlockNo 0
Append transaction queue size: 500

The tip of the local node: SlotNo 63654709
Connecting to the node using socket: /home/manuelpadilla/source/tools/cardano-node-1.35.0-linux2/db/node.socket
[chain-index:Debug:11] [2022-07-17 02:13:00.78 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: SELECT "t0"."row_slot" AS "res0", "t0"."row_block_id" AS "res1", "t0"."row_block_number" AS "res2" FROM "tips" AS "t0" ORDER BY "t0"."row_slot" DESC;
-- With values: []
Starting webserver on port 9083
A Swagger UI for the endpoints are available at http://localhost:9083/swagger/swagger-ui
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:02.79 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: DELETE FROM "tips" WHERE ("row_slot")>(?);
-- With values: [SQLInteger 62510369]
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:02.79 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: DELETE FROM "utxo_out_refs" WHERE EXISTS (SELECT "t0"."output_row_tip__row_slot" AS "res0", "t0"."output_row_out_ref" AS "res1" FROM "unspent_outputs" AS "t0" WHERE (("t0"."output_row_tip__row_slot")>(?)) AND (("row_out_ref")=("t0"."output_row_out_ref")));
-- With values: [SQLInteger 62510369]
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:14.08 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: DELETE FROM "unspent_outputs" WHERE ("output_row_tip__row_slot")>(?);
-- With values: [SQLInteger 62510369]
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:14.08 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: DELETE FROM "unmatched_inputs" WHERE ("input_row_tip__row_slot")>(?);
-- With values: [SQLInteger 62510369]
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:14.08 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: SELECT "t0"."output_row_tip__row_slot" AS "res0", "t0"."output_row_out_ref" AS "res1" FROM "unspent_outputs" AS "t0";
-- With values: []
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:14.79 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: SELECT "t0"."input_row_tip__row_slot" AS "res0", "t0"."input_row_out_ref" AS "res1" FROM "unmatched_inputs" AS "t0";
-- With values: []
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:14.86 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: SELECT "t0"."row_slot" AS "res0", "t0"."row_block_id" AS "res1", "t0"."row_block_number" AS "res2" FROM "tips" AS "t0" ORDER BY "t0"."row_slot" ASC;
-- With values: []
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:15.85 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: DELETE FROM "tips" WHERE ("row_slot")>(?);
-- With values: [SQLInteger 62510369]
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:15.86 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: DELETE FROM "utxo_out_refs" WHERE EXISTS (SELECT "t0"."output_row_tip__row_slot" AS "res0", "t0"."output_row_out_ref" AS "res1" FROM "unspent_outputs" AS "t0" WHERE (("t0"."output_row_tip__row_slot")>(?)) AND (("row_out_ref")=("t0"."output_row_out_ref")));
-- With values: [SQLInteger 62510369]
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:27.56 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: DELETE FROM "unspent_outputs" WHERE ("output_row_tip__row_slot")>(?);
-- With values: [SQLInteger 62510369]
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:27.56 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: DELETE FROM "unmatched_inputs" WHERE ("input_row_tip__row_slot")>(?);
-- With values: [SQLInteger 62510369]
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:27.56 UTC] RollbackSuccess: New tip is Tip(Slot 62510369, BlockId d931221f9bc4cae34de422d9f4281a2b0344e86aac6b31eb54e2ee90f44a09b9, BlockNumber 3680594)
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:27.56 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: DELETE FROM "tips" WHERE ("row_slot")>(?);
-- With values: [SQLInteger 62510369]
[chain-index:Info:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:27.56 UTC] Syncing (98.20%). Processed 0 blocks, 1 rollbacks in the last 11s. Current tip is Point(Slot 62510369, BlockId d931221f9bc4cae34de422d9f4281a2b0344e86aac6b31eb54e2ee90f44a09b9)
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:27.56 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: DELETE FROM "utxo_out_refs" WHERE EXISTS (SELECT "t0"."output_row_tip__row_slot" AS "res0", "t0"."output_row_out_ref" AS "res1" FROM "unspent_outputs" AS "t0" WHERE (("t0"."output_row_tip__row_slot")>(?)) AND (("row_out_ref")=("t0"."output_row_out_ref")));
-- With values: [SQLInteger 62510369]
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:39.04 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: DELETE FROM "unspent_outputs" WHERE ("output_row_tip__row_slot")>(?);
-- With values: [SQLInteger 62510369]
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:39.04 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: DELETE FROM "unmatched_inputs" WHERE ("input_row_tip__row_slot")>(?);
-- With values: [SQLInteger 62510369]
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:39.04 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: SELECT "t0"."output_row_tip__row_slot" AS "res0", "t0"."output_row_out_ref" AS "res1" FROM "unspent_outputs" AS "t0";
-- With values: []
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:39.68 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: SELECT "t0"."input_row_tip__row_slot" AS "res0", "t0"."input_row_out_ref" AS "res1" FROM "unmatched_inputs" AS "t0";
-- With values: []
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:39.77 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: SELECT "t0"."row_slot" AS "res0", "t0"."row_block_id" AS "res1", "t0"."row_block_number" AS "res2" FROM "tips" AS "t0" ORDER BY "t0"."row_slot" ASC;
-- With values: []
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:40.69 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: DELETE FROM "tips" WHERE ("row_slot")>(?);
-- With values: [SQLInteger 62510369]
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:40.69 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: DELETE FROM "utxo_out_refs" WHERE EXISTS (SELECT "t0"."output_row_tip__row_slot" AS "res0", "t0"."output_row_out_ref" AS "res1" FROM "unspent_outputs" AS "t0" WHERE (("t0"."output_row_tip__row_slot")>(?)) AND (("row_out_ref")=("t0"."output_row_out_ref")));
-- With values: [SQLInteger 62510369]
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:52.59 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: DELETE FROM "unspent_outputs" WHERE ("output_row_tip__row_slot")>(?);
-- With values: [SQLInteger 62510369]
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:52.59 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: DELETE FROM "unmatched_inputs" WHERE ("input_row_tip__row_slot")>(?);
-- With values: [SQLInteger 62510369]
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:52.59 UTC] RollbackSuccess: New tip is Tip(Slot 62510369, BlockId d931221f9bc4cae34de422d9f4281a2b0344e86aac6b31eb54e2ee90f44a09b9, BlockNumber 3680594)
[chain-index:Info:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:52.59 UTC] Syncing (98.20%). Processed 0 blocks, 1 rollbacks in the last 11s. Current tip is Point(Slot 62510369, BlockId d931221f9bc4cae34de422d9f4281a2b0344e86aac6b31eb54e2ee90f44a09b9)
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:52.59 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: DELETE FROM "tips" WHERE ("row_slot")>(?);
-- With values: [SQLInteger 62510369]
[chain-index:Debug:33] [2022-07-17 02:13:52.59 UTC] BeamLogItem: SqlLog: DELETE FROM "utxo_out_refs" WHERE EXISTS (SELECT "t0"."output_row_tip__row_slot" AS "res0", "t0"."output_row_out_ref" AS "res1" FROM "unspent_outputs" AS "t0" WHERE (("t0"."output_row_tip__row_slot")>(?)) AND (("row_out_ref")=("t0"."output_row_out_ref")));
-- With values: [SQLInteger 62510369]
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what system you are having a problem with. You mentioned that your cardano-node is 100% synced - is your issue with your local cardano-db-sync? What errors/warnings are you getting in the log file? Share some log details here.

Comment: Im not using cardano-db-sync.   
  
The problem is with plutus-app cardano-chain-index, need to run pab.  
Im using WSL and ubuntu.  
 
There is not error, just repeting all the time:  
 
[chain-index:Info:33] [2022-07-17 01:06:05.64 UTC] Syncing (98.21%). Processed 0 blocks, 1 rollbacks in the last 12s. Current tip is Point(Slot 62510369, BlockId d931221f9bc4cae34de422d9f4281a2b0344e86aac6b31eb54e2ee90f44a09b9) 

Looks like it is doing rollbacks all the new blocks.

Comment: `cardano-node` version `1.35.1` fixes the deserialisation error you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to cardano-db-sync references you found, every repo that is interacting with node has to go through updates to be able to read blocks post Vasil H/F.

> Here also, some report about the chain index rolling back slots after this slot: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/pull/557

As mentioned in the issue, the work for compatibility with Vasil for plutus-apps is being done in [next-node](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/tree/next-node) branch, it's not yet ready for PAB and will likely be part of upcoming release.

Comment: Perfect! I'll be more patience then! Is it normal to release a new version of the blockchain without all the required updates in the infrastructure around? Node, Wallet, Chain Index, Pab, DB-Sync? All the devs are going to pass by problems if we do the other way around. Some products could be in production, and they are going to stop working... don't you think?

Comment: The release being marked on node does not make it ready for mainnet, it's why they did not go for fork on mainnet yet. Currently, node/wallet/dbsync have Vasil ready versions already